# Assume $y(t)$ is a solution of the problem $y''+e^{-t}y'+y=0,y(0)=1,y'(0)=2$ then $(y'(t))^2+(y(t))^2\le 5,\quad \forall t\in[0,\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $y(t)$ is a solution of the problem $$y''+e^{-t}y'+y=0,y(0)=1,y'(0)=2$$
then $$(y'(t))^2+(y(t))^2\le 5,\quad \forall t\in[0,\infty)$$

I have considered to use mean value theorem but did not end up so well.

Then I comment on the $e^{-t}y$ term since as t goes infinity this term vanishes so we end up with $y''+y=0$ which has periodic solution $$c_1 \cos(t)+c_2 \sin(t)$$ and applying initial values we have $$y=\cos(t)+2\sin(t)$$

and taking derivative we see that $y^2+(y')^2\le \sqrt5^2+\sqrt5^2$

If we tried to start with equation as $$y''+y'+y=0$$ assuming $e^{-t}$ is max at $t=0$ so start with maximum (But it doesnot imply maximality of the desired equality so again failed)

**I think there should be more simple way to analyse the question, any hint answer would be appreciated!**

Comment: $\cos t + 2 \sin t = \sqrt{5} \sin (t + \phi)$ so the bound on $y^2 + (y')^2$ van be improved from $10$ you have above to $5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $H = y'^2 + y^2.$ Then, differentiating in $t$, $$H' = 2 y' (y'' + y) = - 2 e^{-t} y'^2 \le 0.$$
So, $H$ is non-increasing for $t \ge 0$. Its initial value is $5$, so we're done.

In physical terms, the $e^{-t} y'$ term in your differential equation is some sort of "friction", dissipating the "total energy" $H$. The fact that it decays to zero for large $t$ is a red herring; this reasoning works if we substitute $e^{-t}$ with any non-negative coefficient.